# How to use Javascript to call an external library's function inside of a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, sha256

Hello so I am using the CryptoJS library to do a SHA256 hash. I am having the problem where it allows me to do something like this.

```
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script>

<script> var p = CryptoJS.sha256("password"); </script>
```

but not this

```
<script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script>

<script>
 function login() {
 var p = CryptoJS.sha256("password");
 } </script>
```

This gives me an undefined function error.

I am new to JavaScript... so I may just not be that familiar with scopes and external libraries could someone help clarify this for me?

Comment: I guess you want to access `p` later on, am i right ? but `p` is only available inside the `login` function. Maybe you could provide us a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

If you call the function `login()` as you have it written all that will happen is that a hash of the word "password" will be generated and assigned to the variable p. -- and that is all!

If you want a working function you need to do something with this variable p. You could start by looking at what is being generated by adding `console.log(p)` inside the function and taking a look at your console.

And if all you are looking for is the hash of "password" you can `return p`.

Good luck!